# Can not import name from X in python

Tags: python, class

i want use Temp-mail lib to create a user. i installed it by `pip install`.
when i want to call the class , it caused an error:

```
import email
File "C:\Users\11\Desktop\email.py", line 4, in <module>

from tempmail import TempMail
ImportError: cannot import name TempMail
```

the code is :

```
import requests
from tempmail import TempMail

tm = TempMail(login='denis', domain='@gnail.pw')
print tm.get_mailbox()  # list of emails in denis@gnail.pw
```

I'm sure there is a class `TempMail` in tempmail.py.

I have read about circular dependency but i do not figure out what the problem is.

edit:

totally , i want to use this site (temp-mail.ru/en) or something like this to generate email address , open it and confirm my registration from others website by click on the link, everything should be done in python and this process again and again when the new email arrived . 
what library do you suggest ? temp-mail ?

last edit i added some lib and the error has been changed /

http://uupload.ir/files/48vt_untitled.jpg

http://uupload.ir/files/dfig_untitled2.jpg

I used another class mail (pythons guerrilla mail) and this error is appeared about the class name.

Comment: What happens, if you only try `python -c 'from tempmail import TempMail'`

Comment: maybe you installed the wrong package, try reinstalling.

Comment: Please post your entire traceback. It looks like your file is named `email.py`, which won't work when you're trying to import a global email package.

Comment: @TheEspinosa did not work. i tried.

Comment: @thebjorn tnx , i wrote my scenario in the next comment under the answer . im not sure it is useful and what library suitable for me.

Comment: You should always add new information to the question itself, but if I understand you correctly, you're looking for a way to circumvent restrictions on a website (which I'm not inclined to help you do).

Comment: @thebjorn you are right. i'm new in stackoverflow. i added new info to first post. i want to use the site that introduce temporary email address and some extra feature like open email text. tnx for your concern

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 modules that install a package called `tempmail` make sure you install only one of those.

1. [temp-mail](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/temp-mail)
2. [tempMail](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tempMail)

You can install `temp-mail`: *(you will need this)*

```
pip install temp-mail
```

You can install `tempMail`:

```
pip install tempMail
```

or

```
pip install tempmail
```

**NOTE:**

If you installed the second one try to remove it first:

```
pip uninstall tempMail
pip install temp-mail
```

if it is not working try this:

```
pip uninstall tempmail
pip install temp-mail
```

Comment: tnx. i want to use this site (https://temp-mail.ru/en/) or something like this to generate email address , open it and confirm my registration by click on link in python and this process again..  what library do you suggest ? temp-mail ?

Comment: @SzabolcsDombi can you see the first post , please. I added extra info with screenshots.