# Can not import name from x in python 2.7

Tags: python, email, import

recently i have created this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44436007/can-not-import-name-from-x-in-python#) and did not get the answer.
after that i edited this and added 2 screenshots.

right now i tested another temporary email library and got the same error :((

this library :

pip install python-guerrillamail

code python 2.7:

```
from guerrillamail import GuerrillaMailSession
session = GuerrillaMailSession()
print session.get_session_state()['email_address']
print session.get_email_list()[0].guid
```

it seemed i cant never work like this email lib.
[image: error screenshot]

updated after remove email.pyc:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\11\Desktop\untitle.py", line 1, in <module>
    from guerrillamail import Guerrillamail
ImportError: cannot import name Guerrillamail
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code to " from guerrillamail import * " that is worked. this code seems import all things to program, maybe it causes to be heavy and executing time.
thanks to @snakecharmerb .

Answer (score 1):

Your module `email.py`, is *shadowing*, or hiding, the `email` package in Python's standard library.  This is causing the error: in the traceback you can see that an error is being reported when the statement `import email` is executed.

Rename your file to something else, for example `myemail.py`.

Comment: i changed the the name. the error appeared again. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\11\Desktop\untitle.py", line 1, in <module>
    from guerrillamail import Guerrillamail
ImportError: cannot import name Guerrillamail

Comment: can you execute the code ? i think the Guerrillamail class has a problem.

Comment: Make sure you delete `email.pyc` from the folder that contains your module.  If there's still a problem, paste the full stacktrace into your question; that will show why the import fails.

Comment: @snakercharmerb thank you for your concern , ok , i removed the file and added stacktrace. if you want i can upload the guerrillamail.py from lib. my python is 2.7.

Comment: Can you add the complete stacktrace, like in the image in your question?  We know the import fails, we want to find out what causes the import to fail.  Running your code works for me, so the library is fine.

Comment: it is the full stacktrace . i upload the last pic for you. there it is : http://uupload.ir/files/zcrh_untitled.png

Comment: i'm noob in python if there is another way to get stacktrace , please tell me. i past the code in the left window and run it , the stacktrace and shell window is appeared .

Comment: What is the output if you execute `from guerrillamail import GuerrillaMailSession` in Idle directly?

Comment: thank you a lot. i changed the code to " from guerrillamail import * " that is worked.